# ubuntu uefi boot issues

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, bootloader

After quite a lot hurdles I got the ubuntu 12.04 installed on my machine in uefi mode but still one issue. It has created a separate boot option in uefi boot mode. So everytime I need to run ubuntu I have to go to bios setup, change the boot order and select ubuntu there and restart machine and similar for windows 8.

So is there any option I can add ubuntu boot details to windows boot loader or window booting details to ubuntu efi boot option.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a computer boot menu on your machine? You could access it by pressing a function key at startup, such as F12 or F9 or F10, similar to pressing F2 to enter Setup. On some machines it comes disabled by default, but you can enable it in bios setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you positive that Ubuntu is booting in EFI mode? Check for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you're booting in EFI mode. If it's absent, you're probably booting in BIOS mode.

If you're booting in EFI mode, then you can reconfigure GRUB to boot Windows, too, and the Boot Repair tool recommended by LovinBuntu will do this, although in an inelegant way that may create complications in the future. Alternatively, you can edit the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file and add an entry like this to it:

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

You may need to change the `set root=` line to point to your EFI System Partition (ESP). Typing `sudo update-grub` will probably get it working. This option isn't guaranteed to work, though; GRUB is pretty finicky about booting Windows in EFI mode, and what works on one system might not work on another.

If you're not booting in EFI mode, then using Boot Repair will just make matters worse. If you're in this boat, then I recommend you check your firmware to be sure that Secure Boot is *disabled* (it's enabled by default on Windows 8 systems) and either re-install Ubuntu *in EFI mode* or install an EFI-mode boot loader. The latter can be tricky if you don't know what you're doing, though. See [my Web page on the topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for details about what's available and how to do it.

Comment: Rod, please can you explain why you write: `If you're not booting in EFI mode, then Boot Repair will just make matters worse` and `may create complications in the future` ? can you point to any bug report describing this ? have you created such report?

Comment: LovinBuntu, Boot Repair relies on an ugly hack (namely, renaming the Windows boot loader and copying GRUB to its original name) to get around ugly firmware bugs. If applied inappropriately, those ugly hacks create complications because other boot loaders and utilities that rely on the Windows boot loader being where it should be won't work correctly. There can also be complications related to BIOS- vs. EFI-mode installations. There are numerous problem reports about this in Web forums, although most of the posters don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Windows entries to your GRUB menu (Ubuntu bootloader) via the `Recommended Repair` of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Thanks Lovin for your response. But actually I was looking for something that Rod has suggested. Boot repair was last option for me.